# Query from Cloud Firestore by timestamp in Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I write a script which removes events from **Cloud Firestore** by *timestamp*. A script run by a link in **Cloud Function**.

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
var db;
var count = 0;

exports.removeOldEvents = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
     db = admin.firestore();
     db.collection("Events")
     .where("timeStamp", "<", new Date())
     .get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
          count = querySnapshot.size;
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
               db.collection("Events").doc(doc.id).delete();
               if (--count == 0) {
                    console.log("Successful ");
                    res.send("Successful ");
                    res.end();
               }
          });
     }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error ", error);
          res.send("Error ", error);
     });

 });
```

What I need to write together:

```
new Date()
```

in order to remove old events by timeStamp?

Thanks!!!

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: How to remove old event by timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling in parallel several asynchronous tasks (i.e. through the [`delete()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#delete) method) and you should send back the response only when all these tasks are completed.

Since the `delete()` method returns a Promise, you need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), as follows:

```
....
exports.removeOldEvents = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  db = admin.firestore();
  db.collection('Events')
    .where('timeStamp', '<', new Date())
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
      var promises = [];
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        promises.push(
          db
            .collection('Events')
            .doc(doc.id)
            .delete()
        );
      });
      return Promise.all(promises);
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Successful');
      res.send('Successful');
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('Error ', error);
      res.status(500).send('Error ', error);
    });
});
```

Note that when you will call this HTTPS Cloud Function the value of `new Date().getTime()` will be now. So I make the assumption that you have some documents with a `timeStamp` value that is in the future, or you will most likely delete the entire collection!

---

Also note that if you are sure your query will return less than 500 document, you could use a [batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes).